# How to boot a system in a second HD but runing the system in another one?

Tags: dual-boot, virtual-machine

I have two computers, but the old one is not working well. So I'd like to install the old hard disk on the new computer.

I know how to do this and I know how to access the data from `sdb`. But I have some old programs installed on `sdb` which I'm not able to install them again on `sda`.

So, I'd like to know if it is possible to use some virtual machine (I have installed VM on `sda`) to boot from `sdb` so that I'd be able to use my old programs whenever I need.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 on both disks. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you told us what the programs are, someone could suggest an alternative way of installing them, so you would not have to fiddle with installation. Also, since both systems are 10.04, maybe you could copy the programs, their data and libraries, to `/usr/local` and see whether they work?

Comment: Some registered programs, like Maple, for example. The problem of copying their folders is to be sure that all the necessary files were copy.

Comment: well, at least you could try and see what happens, and when it fails, ask a question here :-) There are plenty ways of finding out what is missing, including searching for files installed at the same time and differential file lists. From Maple web page: "A Maple 15 license file (license.dat) will be saved in the license folder of your Maple 15 installation"

Answer (score 3):

If both hard disks have Ubuntu 10.04, then I don't think there's any point in running a virtual machine. Why not just use `chroot`? If sdb is mounted to `/media/olddrive`, then you can run:-

```
$ sudo chroot /media/olddrive
```

Quite often though, you'll need access to all the system device folders in `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys`. In which case, you can use `mount` to create them:-

```
$ sudo mount -t devtmpfs none /media/olddrive/dev
$ sudo mount -t devpts   none /media/olddrive/dev/pts
$ sudo mount -t proc     none /media/olddrive/proc
$ sudo mount -t sysfs    none /media/olddrive/sys
```

Of course you can boot from raw hard disks though, with VirtualBox... 
It should come with a tool `VBoxManage`, which can create a ".vmdk" file that is basically a shortcut to the root of a hard drive partition. [See here](http://2stech.ca/index.php/linux/linuxtutotials/readmes/128-mount-a-physical-disk-in-virtualbox) for a little guide on doing this. Note, this latter method isn't really recommended, but I've used it a few times and haven't had any problems with it. One gotcha is that you might have to run VirtualBox with extended (e.g. sudo) privileges to access the raw hard drive partition.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't understand anything. But I'll try to learn. I don't know if I was clear with my aim. If I mount the hard disk as you said how could I fake a boot from it? How to use some programs installed on it?

Comment: You don't need to "fake a boot", when using chroot. As you're already booted into Ubuntu, `chroot` just starts a new bash terminal where the path `/media/olddrive` is interpreted as `/`, thereby changing the 'root' folder. To login to your user account on sdb, you can enter the command `login`. From this terminal, you can then run any programs installed on /dev/sdb

Comment: Great! So after mount it I should only execute `$ sudo chroot /media/olddrive`? This will open the new terminal? Or I have to execute all those other commands cited by you? Second: is it possible to run programs with graphical interface, like Maple, for example? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Note that `chroot` will actually start the bash shell at `/media/olddrive/bin/bash`, which will run as the 'root' user. To go back to your running Operating System's shell, type `exit`. I'd recommend always running `login` immediately after `chroot` btw; otherwise you'll be running programs as the root user, which is a bit dangerous. From this user shell, you'll then have to enter `exit` twice to get back to the running OS's shell. GUI programs will probably require you to run those other commands too - do this before you enter the chroot environment.

Comment: If you have problems with GUI applications being unable to access your X server (the display), [see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) for info on "Accessing graphical applications inside the chroot".